# CSS padding shorthand confusion

Tags: css, padding

```
padding:45px 65px 95px;
```

Why is it that the shorthand above would set the LEFT padding to 65px when a value for the left padding was not even given?

This is a little confusing to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed confusing, but it's just the was CSS works. If you specify 1 value, it will be used for all four sides. If you specify two, the first will be the `top/bottom` padding and the second will be `left/right`. So when specifying three, it goes `top, left/right, bottom`, echoing the usage for when only two values are provided.

Comment: I'm guessing the way that they'd intended for authors to read a shorthand with three values for four sides is `top, sides, bottom`. The spec doesn't give anything but technical requirements, though. Indeed, all it implies is that unspecified values are computed by taking from their opposite sides.

Answer (score 5):

The order is: **Top, Right, Bottom, Left**

Think *TRBL* (trouble). Or clockwise.

When using shorthand, the *opposite* side's value is used if not given. In your case, using `65px` for *left* with the `65px` from *right*.

To take this further, if I had:

```
padding: 10px 20px;
```

Would result in `10px` for *top* and *bottom* and `20px` for right and left.

Finally:

```
padding: 10px;
```

Would result in 10px for everything.

Comment: Or just clockwise from 12 o'clock :)

Answer (score 4):

The shorthand notation always copies the missing elements from their opposite values.

```
padding: top right bottom left; 
padding: top right; // bottom = top, left = right
padding: top right bottom; // left = right
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the sequence is top, right, bottom, left. If only two values are given it will take same for top & bottom and left & right. As you have given 65px to right so its taking same for left.

Answer (score -3):

It's shorthand notation, usually you provide only 2, not 3 arguments, like:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This means 0 in top and bottom, auto in left and right.

Comment: Except the question doesn't ask about shorthands with 2 values!

Answer (score -3):

The order is top, right, bottom, left. When you omit a number, it picks the opposite value:

```
x = t=x, r=x, b=x, l=x
x,y = t=x, r=y, b=x, l=y
x,y,z = t=x, r=y, b=z, l=y
```

Comment: this is wrong. it copies the the missing ones from their opposites.

Comment: The error is fixed, but the explanation is still wrong. It doesn't "start from the beginning".